# how do you update flash

Tags: flash

Is there a simple way to update flash?  firefox reports it is out of date and not safe.

Answer (score 2):

To update flash to the latest version, open the Terminal and enter the following -

`sudo apt-get install --reinstall flashplugin-installer`

This will reinstall the package `flashplugin-installer` which will in turn fetch the latest flashplugin tarball and install it.